# How to repair ruined or evacuated facilities?

Tags: halcyon-6

For Halcyon 6: Starbase Commander, there are a number of facilities that have a little skull over them saying "ruined facility" and do not produce resources.  How can I repair these facilities?

Also any facility gives you the option to abandon the facility, if you do this, the facility becomes "evacuated" and does not produce resources.  How can I fix one of these and send colonists back to them?

Comment: Thanks @TimmyJim I couldn't create the halcyon tag, need more rep before I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Although Vemonus's answer was right at the time, the most recent updates for Halcyon 6 do now allow repairing ruined facilities.

You'll need to make sure you're on at least patch 1.1 (as this was when it was introduced). Then visit any ruined facility and you will be given an option to send an officer on an away mission in the View Sector menu to rebuild the facility.

This costs crew and the different facility types are repaired quicker by different officer types.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, it looks like you are **not** able to repair these ruined facilities.

From [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/halcyon6/comments/4gm4cl/everything_is_in_ruins/):

> I know the devs probably want a way to limit access to resources early in the game, but as far as I know once they're in ruins they stay in ruins, which kind of screws you for later.

And [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/halcyon6/comments/552gls/can_you_rebuild_ruined_facilities/):

> You cannot rebuild ruined facilities

---

As for your question about returning to a planet after evacuating it, I found [this](http://www.thedrastikmeasure.com/2016/05/22/halcyon-6-starbase-commander-pc-review-by-boxcathero/):

> There is also an option to evacuate planets to gain extra crew at the cost of the production of the planet.

This implies that evacuating the planet is permanent and you won't be able to send colonists back.